# Slow parallel memory access in OpenCL / nVidia, what did I miss?

Tags: performance, opencl, nvidia

I'm playing around with OpenCL, Geforce GTX550 and driver version 331.38 from Ubuntu 14.04. What stumps me is the speed of copying from global to local memory. As far as I know, the following code should do coalesced access to global memory:

```
void toLocal(__local float* target, const __global float* source, int count) {
    const int iterations = (count + get_local_size(0) - 1) / get_local_size(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        int idx = i * get_local_size(0) + get_local_id(0);
        if (idx < count)
            target[idx] = source[idx];
    }
}
```

In practice, the following code (which should use all threads to copy the same float over and over again) is measurably faster:

```
void toLocal(__local float* target, const __global float* source, int count) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        target[i] = source[i];
}
```

Both source and target point directly at the beginning of a buffer, so I would guess they are correctly aligned. Group size is 16 by 16, trying to use all threads makes the code more complex but doesn't affect speed. The optimal coalescing group size would be 128 bytes or 32 floats, but as far as I know, on compute model 2 cards (which GTX550 is) the penalty of using only a part or even permuting the elements shouldn't be that bad. Adding local memory fence to the first version makes it only slower. Is there anything else I missed?

EDIT: Changing group size to 32 by 32 made the parallel version roughly as fast as sequential 16 by 16 and made the sequential version slightly slower. Still not the speed improvement I was expecting.

Comment: What happens if you set `-cl-opt-disable` build option? It disables optimization. In the second code, the combiler is probably realizing that same variables are copied again and again and optimizing it to one copy.

Comment: What is the sort of speed you are expecting? According to [this material by NVIDIA](http://sa09.idav.ucdavis.edu/docs/SA09_NVIDIA_IHV_talk.pdf), access to global memory has a very high latency (slide 9).

Comment: Exact numbers are hard to tell, because actual kernel this code is from spends most of its time doing other things.

Comment: The actual speeds are somewhere between 19.2 ms (my parallel copy or async_work_group_copy on 32x32, for loop on 16x16) to 20.8 ms (parallel copy on 16x16, for loop on 32x32). The high latency of global memory is the exact reason I am copying things to local memory. What mystifies me is why copying a convolution kernel to local memory improves the speed so little.

Comment: The first version has a lot of overhead. Could you modify it to be simpler and try again? Something like `for (int idx = get_local_id(0); idx < count; idx += get_local_size(0)) target[idx] = source[idx];`. Also, what do you mean by `group size [...] 32 by 32`? You're only using one dimension here.

Comment: Good point. Eliminating the multiplications made the kernel slightly faster. The rest of the kernel is 2D but I tried to make the copying part as simple as possible in order to figure out where the speed difference is coming. After writing the question I tried a 2D copy with 32x32 workgroups, that seems to be the fastest version so far at 19.1 ms per call.